# IE7 + css classes inheritance

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, styles, knockout.js

I use knockout js to render my UI. Besides I use reset.css to clear my styles. I have this in my reset css:

```
ol, ul {
list-style-image:none;
list-style-position:outside;
list-style-type:none;
}
```

And in my style file:

```
.wysiwyg ol, .wysiwyg ul
{
    list-style: inherit !important;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.wysiwyg ol li
{
    list-style: decimal outside;
}
.wysiwyg ul li
{
    list-style: disc outside;
}
```

And the problem is in that the style for lists doesn't applies in IE7. But when I use IE9 in emulation mode and press 'Edit' button and than save the markup everything goes OKAY.
So I think this is a problem of css classes chaining and inheritance.
Could someone help in advance how to force IE7 to use my css class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE <8 has massive problems with inheritance. the easiest way to get around this is to redeclare the styles instead of inheriting, if that is possible for you.

you could also try to use [ie7-js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/), wich tries to make IE7 behaving like a standards-compliant browser. it works pretty good, but isn't perfect: you may get problems when using a reset-stylesheet. just try it out and see if it works for you.

a third possibility is to make use of IEs css-expressions like this (note: this is typed straight from my head, not tested - but you should get the idea):

```
list-style:inherit; /* standards-compliant browsers */
//list-style:expression(this.parentNode.currentStyle['listStyle']); /* IE */
```